# why "Show detail" segue is not usable in my splitview?

Tags: swift

Hi this is my first encounter with this, I have been using splitview before but this one is odd. Could anyone help me how to fix this?

[image]

I setted the app for ipad with 8.0 minimum deployment target

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should enable the "Size Classes", this is one of the problem that cause this.

Comment: "show", "show detail",  "popover presentation" and "present modally" are available if you're using size classes.

Comment: thanks man, since im using autolayouts might as well turn on the enable size classes